# Button within popover not working

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

SORRY. Just clicked. I was releasing the button at the end.

OK, almost finished on my first iPad app, all is looking good EXCEPT.....

I have a button that causes a popover to appear. The popover contains a variable number of buttons. With the limited look and feel, the corporate branding calls for a UIImageView containing an image, a label on top, then finally a custom button covering it all to act as a pretty button.

I would like to perform a quick transaction against our database prior to dismissing the button as the info in the popup is highly time sensitive and if anyone leaves it visible for more than 30 seconds, the content may not be current.

So DetailViewController starts the popover, the popover retrieves the current data and generates the content, which may be a number of instances of the button. Theoretically, when the button is pressed, it calls an execute function within popoverVeiwController via.....

```
        UIButton *pButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [pButton addTarget:self action:@selector(execute:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        pButton.tag = [[[[pLines objectAtIndex:loop] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        [pButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, (((loop-1)*40)+5), 200, 30)];
        [self.view addSubview:pButton];
        [pButton release];
```

within popoverViewController I have defined execute to NSLog immediately, however nothing happens.

I know I am missing something simple, however stackOverflow does not quite answer my question, Google has not been able to clear it up for me, and dont even ask about Siri!

Have I the right structure? Is calling 'execute' within the popoverViewController .m the correct method?

Thanks in advance
Chris H

Comment: Removing the release from the button solved the problem.

Comment: Add that as an answer, then, it is OK to answer your own question. Once you've accepted the answer it removes it from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I released the button.